# RadioGroup - why does the button did not change color after selecting every radiobutton

Tags: android

I have done the radiogroup for this fragment using if else while unclickable. I tried testing it, but it remains the same. Can you please figure out what is the problem with this?

public class Competencies extends Fragment {

```
View rootView;
Button submit;
TextView title;
RadioGroup rg1, rg2, rg3, rg4;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.competencies, container, false);
    RadioGroup();
    submit = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    submit.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF00574B")));
    submit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
    submit.setClickable(false);
    title = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null) {
        title.setText(bundle.getString("title"));
    }
    Submit();
    return rootView;
}

public void RadioGroup(){
    rg1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rgFirstQuestion);
    rg2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rgSecondQuestion);
    rg3 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rgThirdQuestion);
    rg4 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rgFourthQuestion);
}
public void Submit()
{
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1 && rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1 && rg3.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1 && rg4.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1) {

            }
            else
            {
                submit.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF4CC8B7")));
                submit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
                submit.setClickable(true);
                CompetenciesSuccessful successful = new CompetenciesSuccessful();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,successful).commit();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Does getCheckedRadioButtonId() not return the view Id for the button? I believe you might need to use rg1.isChecked() or something similar

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
public void Submit(){
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(rg1.isChecked() && rg2.isChecked() && rg3.isChecked() && rg4.isChecked()) {
            submit.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF4CC8B7")));
            submit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
            submit.setClickable(true);
            CompetenciesSuccessful successful = new CompetenciesSuccessful();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,successful).commit();

        }
```

Comment: RadioGroup does not allow isChecked() statements. They only use getCheckedRadioButtonId().

Comment: rg1 is not radioGroup rather it is a radio button @Chua Teng Sheng